# access online database with objective-c

Tags: objective-c

I am studying a book and learned that to traffic information server (specifically database) for the existing application on the iphone or ipad, I read that it is necessary to use the website to generate an xml or json and hence starting Objective-C read and make the interpretation.

Hence I would like to know if it is possible to do this in a direct way, instead of generating the xml or json, I would connect directly to the server, creating a place in my application where I put the server ip and authentication, thereby I can do a select, insert, delete directly from the existing database into the server

some help?

Comment: way too broad... currently the answer to "is it possible?" would be "yes."

Comment: as I said: too broad ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by using webservices, you just want to do database operations right ?
Json Parsing is used when you want to display some data from a site to your app.

Comment: Well i come from the php, and in php i can do this! have a place where i put the IP server and put the login and password, so i need to create a program in ios who do this, for me, you have any tutorials?

Comment: - a) op wants no web service, b) he wants no XML or JSON, BUT I'd ignore this too as it is likely wrong BUT this post is a PURE guess as the question has NO info and a serious answer can't be given :)

Comment: then the only way I see is to send a parameter via post method to a project. php php and it does the job, it will be one of the correct solutions? if appropriate to do so will be that some of you can give me some tutorial where I send a parameter to a separate page?

Comment: @user3177502, yes, take that route. search for ios post and you will find tutorials.

Comment: That's possible via calling a webservice method(which accepts user id,password as parameter & returns a flag upon checking from database) from your IOS app, search that i guess..